# Complex analysis - equation of functions such as $C(x)=K(y)$

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

small question:
Let us have $C(x)$, which is a general function that depend on x.
same with $K(y)$, which is a general function that depend on y.
Let us say we have:

1. $C(x)=K(y)$
   can we say that $C(x)=K(y)=constant$?
   because the problem is with [3]
2. $C(x)+2x=K(y)+3y$
   Can I say such a function exist?
3. $C(x)+2xy=K(y)$
   I know if we have equation like that, it means that the equation does not exist ( it is not possible ).
   Then how does [1] and [2] are possible? it is basically the same.

Comment: What is the context you are seeing 3? In my opinion 1 and the conclusion you draw is correct, 3 is contradictory. And 2 is OK if $C = -2x, K = -3y$

Comment: **1)** If $C(x) = K(y)$ *for all* $x,y$ in some appropriate domain, then you are correct, both functions are equal to the same constant.  **2)** Functions $C,K$ that satisfy $C(x) + 2x = K(y) + y$ *do* exist. Take $C(x) := \alpha - 2x$ for any number $\alpha$ and determine $K$ as a function of $y.$ A similar example can be made reversing the roles of $C$ and $K.$ You should note that for $C,K$ to satisfy that equation, each side must be constant.  **3)** Such $C,K$ *cannot* exist, but this equation is *very* different from (1) and (2).

Comment: Problem is the logic, the math I understand why,............ I can not try to think of a logic to how it is possible that a one sided X functions will be equal to Y function. I mean, you have from one side 5x and from other side 6y, so $5x=6y$, it doesn't come to me ( related probably to 2) )

Comment: @LearningToCode Any constant function is a function of whatever variable you like. On the other hand, if you have an equation like $C(x) + \mathrm{something}(x) = K(y) + \mathrm{something}(y),$ this just means that $C$ and $K$ must "cancel" the "something" dependence so the equation holds. Each side neutralizes its own variable dependence so the equation overall reduces to a constant being equal to other constant (in fact, the same constant).

Comment: Ohh, so let us say we have $C(x)+5x=K(y)+6y$, so it basically means that $C(x)=-5x$ and $K(y)=-6y$, if I Understand correctly?....... Or it will be $C(x)=-5x+cons1$ and $K(y)=-6y + const2$

Comment: @LearningToCode Yes. That example corresponds to an equation $0 = 0.$ You can have an arbitrary constant there, like $C(x) = \alpha - 5x$ and $K(y) = \alpha - 6y.$ In fact, these examples are the only solutions. You have to use the same constant for each function so the equation holds.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much!! now I understand basically all :) and I understand also why 3 does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes. If $y_1,y_2\in\Bbb R$, then $K(y_1)=C(0)=K(y_2)$; in particular, $K(y_1)=K(y_2)$. So, $K$ is constant. For the same reason, $C$ is constant.
2. You can take, say, $C(x)=-2x$ and $K(y)=-3y$. Then $C(x)+2x=K(y)+3y$.
3. No such pair of functions can exist. If it did, then $K(y)-C(1)=2y$ and $K(y)-C\left(\frac12\right)=y$, and therefore$$C\left(\frac12\right)-C(1)=\bigl(K(y)-C(1)\bigr)-\bigr(K(y)-C\left(\frac12\right)\bigr)=y;$$that is, $y$ would be constant, which is absurd.

It's up to you to tell us why you see 1. and 2. as being basically the same thing as 3.

Comment: I managed to understand everything, thanks to your help and to @Edd.
Huge appreciation to both of you :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.